# How to disable systemd from creating mount units when a mount command is run

Tags: systemd, mount

We are transitioning from an old initd system to systemd. We have a lot of mounts that we manually manage, systemd is creating .mount units for each and every mount point that we create using mount command. It is also creating .mount unit for each every subdirectory under the mount points resulting in thousands of mount units. It tries to mount/unmount them when our system is rebooted. Some of these mounts are shared across systems and when systemd is mounting/unmounting automatically is causing the systems to crash.

How do I disable systemd from auto creating mount units when we run mount commands inside our scripts? We use systemd version 247. I have already tried masking various services like 'systemd-udevd-control.socket, systemd-udevd-kernel.socket, systemd-udev-trigger.service' that did not work. I also tried using noauto option while running mount command that did not work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thnks for the help in advance.

--Srinivas

Comment: Can't reproduce! Systemd does create a .mount unit in /run/systemd/generator for each entry in /etc/fstab, but when I manually mount something, it doesn't. Also, it does *not* create mount units for subdirectories of my mount points. As I agree with you, that would make no sense. So, there's most likely something special about what you do that leads to this!

Comment: What do you think I might be doing is causing this? Like I aid moving from initd to systemd so it should be using the default systemd configuration. We are using version 247 on Debian Buster.

Comment: I don't know, sorry. How are you mounting things?

Comment: Just regular mount command.

Comment: I am using the regular mount command to mount. 
Eg: mount /dev/sda6 /tmp/rootfs

Once I mount if I grep for my mount I see a mount for each directory under /dev/sda6 and a 'systemctl list-units --type=mount' shows a corresponding .mount file.
Not sure who or what is creating them, I want the mounts and the .mount files not to be created and managed by systemd. I want to manually mount/unmount them. 
How do I configure that on systemd?